# How to get user ID on the registration and add in to custom table

Tags: database, wordpress

I am trying to get user ID on registration and automatically add that ID to my custom table. I am using wp-members plugin for registration.

So is it possible to get user ID on the fly while registering and add that ID to another custom table with WP-Members plugin.

Or I can use custom registration page if require. But need some guideline how to get user ID on the fly during registration.

I am adding below code to my theme functions.php but nothing works.. I dont know where I am wrong or this code is completely wrong?

```
function get_customs_id($user_id){
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->insert( 'wp_customs', array( 'customs_id' => 'value1' ), array( '%d' ) );
}
add_filter('user_register', 'get_customs_id');
```

Please help me to make it works.. :)

Answer (score 0):

With the exception of the fact that 'user_register' is an action hook and not a filter, that should work.

Looking at the date on the question, it's possible that the plugin did not make use of wp_insert_user at that time.  I'm not certain.  But it does now, so that hook should work.

There is also an action hook specific to the plugin that could be used as well - [wpmem_post_register_data](http://rocketgeek.com/plugins/wp-members/users-guide/filter-hooks/wpmem_post_register_data).  This hook comes after the user is registered and inserted in the db.  It receives an array of all of the user fields which includes the id.

So using that hook and your other code, this should work:

```
function get_customs_id($fields){
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->insert( 'wp_customs', array( 'customs_id' => $fields['ID'] ), array( '%d' ) );
}
add_filter('user_register', 'get_customs_id');
```